# Blender Cycles - Alpha Over Node - How to get a combination of two layers and get as result something like 1 layer over the other?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, transparency, layers

Maybe the title is hard to understand so I explain quickly. I have 2 layers, one with a flat text and the other one with the outline of the text (freestyle). If I combine both (with Alpha Over) the resulting image is not the same as if I render on the same layer text plus the contour. It seems like the outline is less "strong" when I'm combining the layers in comparison with a direct render of object + contour.
[image: Split view between Alpha Over 2 layers combination and the direct render]

As it can be seen on the image (on a subtle way) on the combination between layers, the stroke is a little bit less strong as the full render. How do I do to get exactly the same result as the full render when I combine two layers?

Thanks,
Gonzalo

Comment: Try with EXRs. Blender’s alpha handling is broken in many instances. If you find yourself having to use the “Convert Premul” check box, you are doing it wrong. Rendering path tracers can only generate associated alpha, and therefore never require that toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Alpha Over takes **transparency** into account. Composite using Z-Combine node instead. You connect Render Layers' Color and Z directly to the node.

Comment: Hi, now it looks better but still is not the same. But thanks to your answer, by chance I've got the exact result: using Z Combine (as you've recommended me) connect "text" layer and Z value to Z Combine inputs and the "contour" layer connect the image output to the color input and on Z input connect "alpha" instead of Z. I'm not sure if I've explained well myself and I don't understand what's going on, but it just works! Thank you so much!!!